# Virtualization: Can I built a 4-core virtual CPU with many physicals processors?

Tags: amazon-web-services, simulation, virtualization, processor, vcpu

I use a mechanical simulation software that take 5-10 hours to resolve one simulation. My licence software is limited to 4-core.

Spec of machine that actualy run the software:

- Windows 7 Pro
- 1x Xeon E5-2650 v2 2.60GHz (8-core)
- 32GB Ram
- SSD

I'm trying to find a way to reduce as much as possible the time of simulation.

In virtualization, is it possible to take for exemple, 2x physical 8-core 2.50GHz CPU and make a vCPU of 4-core at 10GHz per core? Each virtual core will take 4 physicals core in this exemple. Is this possible to make it?

Any suggestion?

It is possible to use AWS EC2 Amazon server to make it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon EC2 is available in a variety of [Instance Types](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/). Each type has a set number of virtual CPUs, RAM, etc. Each vCPU is a hyperthread of an Intel Xeon core, so you might want to check your licensing to confirm how it defines a 'core'.

By choosing Instance Type, you can control how many CPUs you get and you will know the type of processor being used. However, you cannot combine CPUs to make a *faster* CPU.